# jqGrid Cell Editing Locally

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid, editing

I'm trying to implement a jqGrid with editable cells:

```
var myGrid = $("#mygrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: mydata,
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'Serial', width: 1040, editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
                ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#mypager',
            sortname: 'Serial',
            cellEdit: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                if(id && id!==lastSel){
                    jQuery('#mygrid').restoreRow(lastSel); 
                    lastSel=id; 
                }
                jQuery('#mygrid').editRow(id, true); 
           }
        });
        myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#mypager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: true });
```

However, everytime I try to edit a cell, it allows me to write on it but as soon as I click on other row or even outside the grid, the text dissapear.

Another thing, everytime I hit "enter" it tries to submit something because it shows me the following message:
"No url is set".

And of course, I only want to use this grid 'locally'. After editing the grid the user will have to click on a "Submit" button that is included in the .html and then I will manage the data inserted on the grid.

Thx.

Answer (score 9):

To be able to use [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) locally (you use `cellEdit:true`) you have to use [cellsubmit:'clientArray'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#properties) property.

On the other side you use also [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) function, so you want to use [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing). To be able to use [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) locally you should define `editurl:'clientArray'` (see [documentation here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow)).

More then that you use also `myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#mypager', { edit: true, ...})` which enable [Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing), which has not full local editing support.

I recommend you to use just [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) and include `editurl:'clientArray'` to the options of your jqGrid. The [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) (`cellEdit: true`) and [Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) should be removed.