# Using jqGrid's inline-editing with RESTful urls?

Tags: ajax, rest, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and would like to be able to use its built-in editing functions to make ajax calls to add/edit/delete. Our API uses RESTful verbs and urls like so:

```
verb     url               action
--------------------------------------------------------------
GET      /api/widgets      get all widgets (to populate grid)
POST     /api/widgets      create new widget
PUT      /api/widgets/1    update widget 1
DELETE   /api/widgets/1    delete widget 1
```

Is it possible to use the built-in ajax handling with these restrictions, or do I have to use local data (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513628/jqgrid-cell-editing-locally) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389874/jqgrid-editurl-value-for-local-editing)) and manage the ajax calls myself? If it is possible, what properties do I set on the grid?

(`ajaxRowOptions` looks promising, but the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) is a bit thin on how to use it.)

Comment: Which editing mode you want to use: inline editing, form editing, "actions" formatter or some mix (like add/delete with form editing and edit with inline editing)?

Comment: Ideally, form editing for creating new widgets, inline editing for editing them, and an action icon for deleting them. :) Second choice would probably be the "select-a-row-then-click-a-button" pattern for all three.

Comment: All this is possible, but has just different code. I will try to write the answer in the next time (probably tomorrow). Today I spend too many time for jqGrid and have to go back to my main business. :-)

Answer (score 10):

The usage of `POST` in Add form is by default.

The main idea for customizing jqGrid for RESTfull backend you can find in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731).

To use 'DELETE' in form editing if you use the Delete button of the navigator toolbar. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135173/implementing-delete-and-edit-operations-in-jqgrid/7140029#7140029) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952888/custom-delete-function-in-jqgrid/3953153#3953153). So you should use about the following settings:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {edit: false, add: false, search: false}, {}, {},
    { // Delete parameters
        mtype: "DELETE",
        serializeDelData: function () {
            return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
        },
        onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
            params.url = '/api/widgets/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
        }
    });
```

I use in the example above the [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function to be sure that if the id will have some special characters (spaces for example) if will be encoded so that the server part automatically received the original (decoded) data. Probably you will need to set some additional settings for the `$.ajax` call used during sending Delete request to the server. You can use for it [ajaxDelOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) property.

You can make the above settings as **your default settings**. You can do this with respect of the following

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url = '/api/widgets/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
    }
});
```

The method `onclickSubmit` from the example above can be used for the Edit operations (in case of form editing) to modify the URL dynamically to `/api/widgets/1`. In many cases the usage of `onclickSubmit` in the above form is not possible because one need to use different base urls (`'/api/widgets'`) different grids. In the case one can use

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url += '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
    }
});
```

Then the usage of `navGrid` should be with explicit setting of `url`

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {edit: false, add: false, search: false}, {}, {},
    { // Delete parameters
        url: '/api/widgets'
    });
```

and
To use 'PUT' in inline editing you can set the following default jqGrid settings:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json", type: "PUT", async: true },
    serializeRowData: function (data) {
        var propertyName, propertyValue, dataToSend = {};
        for (propertyName in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
                propertyValue = data[propertyName];
                if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
                    dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
                } else {
                    dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    }
});
```

The setting `contentType: "application/json"` is not required in general, but it could be required for some server technologies. The callback function `serializeRowData` from the example above sent the data as JSON. It is not required for RESTfull, but it's very common. The function `JSON.stringify` is native implemented in the most recent web browsers, but to be sure that it work in old browsers to you should include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) on your page.

The code of `serializeRowData` could be very simple like

```
serializeRowData: function (data) {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

but I use above code to be able to use functions inside of the `extraparam` of the method [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) and the problem description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810885/postdata-not-passing-any-parameters/5811359#5811359)).

The usage of the RESTfull URL (like `/api/widgets/1`) in the `editRow` is very simple:

```
$(this).editRow(rowid, true, null, null, '/api/widgets/' + encodeURIComponent(rowid));
```

To use it in case of the form editing you should use

```
grid.navGrid('#pager', {},
    { mtype: "PUT", url: '/api/widgets' });
```

and

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, // can be not required
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url += '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata.list_id);
    }
});
```

It is important to remark that to get `id` from the `postdata` inside of `onclickSubmit` and need use `postdata.list_id` instead of `postdata.id`, where `'list'` is the id of the grid. To be able to use different grid (`<table>`) ids one can use *new* non-standard parameter. For example, in the code below I use `myGridId`:

```
var myEditUrlBase = '/api/widgets';
grid.navGrid('#pager', {},
    { mtype: "PUT", url: myEditUrlBase, myGridId: 'list' },
    { // Add options
        url: myEditUrlBase },
    { // Delete options
        url: myEditUrlBase });
```

and the default setting defined as

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url += '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
    }
});

$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, // can be not required
    onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
        params.url += '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata[params.myGridId + '_id']);
    }
});
```

In case of the usage of [formatter:'actions'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622779/custom-jqgrid-post-action/6627201#6627201)) with inline or form editing (or a mix) you can use the same technique as described before, but forward all needed Edit/Delete option using `editOptions` and `delOptions` formatoptions.

The last your question was the usage of `GET` as `/api/widgets`. The classical RESTfull services will returns just array of all items as the response on `/api/widgets`. So you should just use `loadonce: true` and `jsonReader` which used methods instead of properties (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)).

```
loadonce: true,
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

You should in some way include information which item property can be used as the id of grid rows. The id must be `unique` on the page. It your data has no id I would recommend you to use

```
id: function () { return $.jgrid.randId(); }
```

as an additional `jsonReader` method because per default the current version of jqGrid use sequential integers ("1", "2", "3", ...) as the row ids. In case of having at least two grids on the same page it will follow to the problems.

If the size of the data returned by 'GET' are more as 100 rows I would you recommend better to use server side paging. It means that you will add an *additional* method in the server part which support server side sorting and paging of data. I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764709/jqgrid-not-loading-data/5766189#5766189) where I described *why* the standard format of the input data are not RESTfull array of items and has `page`, `total` and `records` additionally. The new method will be probably not strange for the classical RESTful design, but the sorting and paging data in *native* or even SQL code can improve the total performance from the side of enduser dramatically. If the names of the standard jqGrid input parameters (`page`, `rows`, `sidx` and `sord`) you can use `prmNames` jqGrid parameter to rename there.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Where in the documentation can I find what the parameters are in a call like: $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {edit: false, add: false, search: false}, {}, {},
    { // Delete parameters
        url: '/api/widgets'
    });

Comment: I assume that's an API call on an already-built grid, but I don't see 'navGrid' in the list of methods on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: @sprugman: I am not sure that I understand correct what you mean. [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) in the documentation of `navGrid` are described `prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView` parameters which are parameters of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) methods `editGridRow`, `delGridRow`, `searchGrid` and `delGridRow`. [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) are described `url` property of `delGridRow` for example.

Comment: Or I guess the "navigator" section is better. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator

Comment: Yeah I found it. I mean, the call to 'navGrid' has a bunch of paramaters `{edit: false, etc.}, {}, {}`. I was trying to find out what those empty braces were for, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out this excellent general tutorial for how to set-up jqGrid for RESTful URL's [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/jqgrid-rest-ajax-spring-mvc-integration.html), which also includes how the corresponding Spring MVC server portion would look.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve it by implementing beforeSubmitCell event handler:

```
beforeSubmitCell: function(rowId) {

            jQuery("#grid-HumanResource-table").jqGrid(
                'setGridParam',
                {
                    cellurl: s.getBaseModule().config.baseAPIUrl + "humanResource/" + rowId
                }
            );
        },
```

I am using jqGrid 4.6 version.