# How can I specify separate URLs for edit and add?

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to specify separate URLs for editing (`editurl`) and adding rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different `prmEdit` and `prmAdd` options of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) you can forward different options to [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) used in "Add" and "Edit" forms. If in both cases you need to use two different *static* URLs you can just use different values for `url` parameters for Add and Edit options.

If you need have different *dynamic* URLs you can use [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler which modify the URL just before the Ajax call. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344310/using-jqgrids-inline-editing-with-restful-urls/7365228#7365228) you can find corresponding code examples.