# jqGrid: Can we configure jqGrid to send customized row id parameter in Ajax post while editing

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to use [jqGrid inline editing with RestFull urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344310/using-jqgrids-inline-editing-with-restful-urls) as mentioned.
Now, when jqGrid posts data to the server, can we change the id query parameter to something else, instead of id.

for example: The server side domain object is say, Customer with customerId as the identity key.

Now, in jqGrid, I set the id in the jsonReader options as

```
jsonReader : {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        cell: "cell",
        id: "customerId"
    },
```

Now, when the data is posted to the server, jqGrid posts `id:something`. I would like to have `customerId:something` as parameter. Is this possible with some jqGrid Configuration or serializeRowData function is the only option.