# JQGrid: creating dynamically a RESTFul URI with id appended

Tags: jqgrid

When submitting the jqGrid form, I want to append '/theRecordId' to the URL, REST style, for the edit use case. This is not working:

```
jQuery("#noteList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {addtitle:"Add New Note", clearAfterAdd: true},
    {addCaption:"Edit Note", mtype:"PUT"
        ,onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata) {
            rp_ge.url = editurl + '/' + postdata.id;  }
     },

    {addCaption:"Add New Note", mtype:"POST"}, 
    {}, 
    {}, 
    {}
  );
```

This results in "/[myurl]/undefined" being sent to the server (where [myurl] is the correct initial editurl).
So the dynamic url manipulation seems to work, but 'id' is undefined. What should be the name of the 'id' property? I can see that what is being passed as a form parameter is 'id'. I also tried noteId, which is the name it has in the incoming data when displaying the grid, and also what I used for jsonReader.id. Didn't work either. Where should this attribute name come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you used an example created for old version of jqGrid. The current version of jqGrid uses `{gridid}_id` as the property of `id` value. For example if the `id` of the grid which you use is `noteList` then `noteList_id` is the name of id property of `postdata` parameter of `onclickSubmit`. It's important to understand that *later*, after calling of `onclickSubmit` and `beforeSubmit`, the name of property will be changed from `noteList_id` to `id` (see [the part of code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L679-L689)).

You can fix the code of `onclickSubmit` to the following

```js
onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
    options.url = editurl + '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata[this.id + "_id"]);
}
```

I included the call of JavaScript function [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) to be sure that URL will be correctly encoded in case of any characters used in `id`.

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg, it worked like a charm! jqGrid is really an amazingly powerful and versatile framework but also it's hard to learn! I hope you're coming up soon with a book :)

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same problem with the DELETE use case. This returns /undefined: {mtype:"DELETE",
     onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
       options.url = editurl + '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata[this.id + "_id"]);
   }}

Comment: @user2309409: format of `postdata` of `onclickSubmit` of Delete form is very simple: it's just `id` value in case of single selection and is comma separated ids of selected rows if you use `multiselect: true`. So if you don't use `multiselect: true` option of jqGrid then you can use `options.url = editurl + '/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata);`. I recommend additionally use `serializeDelData: function () { return ""; }`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7365228/315935)