# Delete a record in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, http, jqgrid

I use jqgrid to show my data, and I am trying to delete a record. I use http DELETE request to send request to server.

I checked my firebug console, It looks like it is not sending `"oper"` and `"id"` to server.

When I Changed the request type to POST it is sending values to server.

Q : How can use DELETE type in jqgrid so that it sends data to sever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP DELETE should don't send and parameters in the body of HTTP request. Instead of that one should append all required options to the URL. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299696/315935) for more information about HTTP DELETE restrictions.

So you should append id to the URL in the form `/{id}` or in the parameters form `?id={id}` depend on the server part which you use. For example the following Delete options appends id in the form `/{id}` to the main delete-URL `"/yourUrl/"`:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager",
    {edit: false, add: false, search: false}, {}, {},
    { // Delete parameters
        mtype: "DELETE",
        serializeDelData: function () {
            return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
        },
        onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
            params.url = "/yourUrl/" + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
        }
    });
```

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7365228/315935) for more details.